# Why are linear maps on real normed spaces not bounded, whereas it is true for $\mathbb{R}^p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, linear-transformations

In the book of *The elements of Real Analysis* by Bartle, it is given that

> Any linear function $f:\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^q$ is continuos,
>   which means $f$ is bounded for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$.

Moreover, in the book of *Linear Algebra* by W. Greub, it is given that

> if $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t  $$||\phi (x)|| \leq M ||x|| \quad
>  x\in E,$$ where $E$ is **any** real normed vector space. Hence, any
>   bounded linear transformation is continuous.

Remark: Bartle works on $\mathbb{R}^p$ and Greub works on $E$.

Now as student who first read the Greub's book, there might be some real normed vector spaces where $f$ might not be bounded, hence is not continuous. However, as far as, Bartle states, if we restrict ourselves to $\mathbb{R}^p$, any linear transformation is bounded, but I couldn't find anything in the proof of Bartle's that only works on $\mathbb{R}^p$, and does not works in general $E$, so my question is that what is the problem in here ? i.e which property of $\mathbb{R}^p$ allows any linear map to be bounded, whereas any real normed does not satisfy in general ?

**Proof:**

> Let $x = \sum_i^p \lambda_i a_i,$ where $\{a_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $E$, and $\{b_i\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $F$. Suppose $dim E = p$, and $dim F = q$,
>
> and let $(\alpha_v^u)_{v,u}$ represent $f:E \to F$ on $\{a_i\}$, and
>   define $M = sup\{|\alpha_v^u|\}$.Then we know that for any $i$,
>   $|\lambda_i| < |x|$.
>
> Now,  $$|f(a_i)| = |\sum_u^q \alpha_v^u b_u| \leq \sum_u^q
>  |\alpha_v^u||b_u| \leq \sum_u^q |b_u| q M$$, hence
>
> $$|f(x)| =| \sum_i^p \lambda_i f(a_i)|\leq \sum_i^p|\lambda_i||f(a_i)|
>  \leq p |x| \sum_i^p|f(a_i)| \leq p |x| q M \sum_u^q |b_u| \leq |x|pq\sqrt{q} M$$
>
> Therefore, the linear map $f$ is bounded, hence it is continuous.

**Edit:**

There was some problems that I have seen in the proof, so I have edited it.

Comment: In extreme synthesis, since $\mathbb R^p$ is locally compact, all linear functions defined in that space are continuous.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro First of all, what does "locally" means ? Secondly, where did we used that property in the proof (for $\mathbb{R}^p$ case) ?

Comment: this is a consequence of Riesz theorem

Comment: @GuyFsone "this" ? What do you mean, I did not get it. Do you mean my claim by "this" ?

Comment: the Riesz theorem for compactness says that in infinite dimension the unite ball is not compact

Comment: @GuyFsone So, as long as, $dim (E) = p$, i.e finite, my claim holds, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globally, you are correct. However, there are some confusing things in what you wrote:

1. You ask “can $\sum_u^q|a_u|$ ever be infinite?” How is that possible? It is a finite sum of real numbers.
2. You write “if I choose $\{a_u\}$ as an orthonormal basis”. That only makes sense if we are dealing with an inner product.

Comment: Can't we induce an inner product from the given norm ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas In general, no. A norm $\|\cdot\|$ is induced by an inner product if and only if $\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=2\bigl(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2\bigr)$.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for pointing out. I have edited the question.

Comment: By the way, what exactly do you mean by "globally" ? I mean when I am not correct ? is it when $E$ is infinite dimensional only ? (as pointed out in the comments)

Comment: @onurcanbektas Your notation is confusing, but it seems to me that you wrote a correct proof of the fact that every linear map between finite-dimensional real normed spaces is bounded.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, there is no such thing as an "orthonormal basis" in a general normed vector space (finite dimensional or infinite dimensional).  To define an orthonormal basis you need an inner product, not just a norm.  Moreover, even if you do have an inner product, there may not exist any orthonormal basis if your vector space is infinite dimensional.

(Note that the assumption that the basis is orthonormal cannot be dropped from the argument as written, since it is needed to conclude that $|\lambda_i|\leq|x|$.)

However, even if your normed vector space has an inner product (which induces the norm) and has an orthonormal basis, the argument still does not work in the infinite-dimensional case.  The problem is that your orthonormal basis will be infinite, and so you will have infinitely many numbers $a^u_v$, and so the supremum $M$ could be infinite.

(To be clear, when I say "orthonormal basis", I mean not the usual notion for infinite dimensional inner product spaces but rather "Hamel basis which is orthonormal".  That is what is needed for the argument, since $f$ is only known to preserve finite sums.)

Comment: As I have stated in the proof, the dimensions of $E$ and $F$ are finite.

Comment: Yes, but your question is where the proof requires finite-dimensionality (or more specifically, for the spaces to be finite-dimensional and Euclidean)...